# Transferindo imagem via socket, a imagem fica preta

Tags: c#, socket, processamento-de-imagens, buffer

O meu servidor manda um comando pra o cliente e o cliente manda uma PrintScreen para o servidor usando esse código:

```
Image printScreen = new Bitmap(monitorWidth, monitorHeight);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printScreen);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printScreen.Size);
printScreen.Save("Test1.jpg"); //Aqui sai uma linda imagem jpg
byte[] bufferTempTemp = imageToByteArray(printScreen);
byteArrayToImage(bufferTempTemp).Save("Test2.jpg"); //Aqui sai uma imagem jpg meio danificada mas tudo bem
byte[] bufferTemp = new byte[4 + bufferTempTemp.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(1), 0, bufferTemp, 0, 4);
Buffer.BlockCopy(bufferTempTemp, 0, bufferTemp, 4, bufferTempTemp.Length);
socketOfClient.Send(bufferTemp);
```

Pronto, o server recebe o pacote tudo normal: (vale lembrar que os primeiros 4bytes do pacote representam um inteiro que é o ID do pacote, 1 significa que é uma imagem chegando)

```
byte[] bufferTemp = new byte[bufferReadOfServer.Length - 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bufferReadOfServer, 4, bufferTemp, 0, bufferReadOfServer.Length - 4);
Image image = byteArrayToImage(bufferTemp);
image.Save("Test3.jpg"); //Aqui sai uma imagem preta :/
```

Agora quando eu vou ver a imagem que foi salva, ela tem 4Kb e é totalmente preta, o tamanho dela é exatamente o tamanho do meu monitor, 1920 x 1080

As funções que convertem bytes em imagem e vice-versa:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Eu já testei a imagem antes do envio, ele realmente printa uma imagem válida, o problema está no recebimento.

Comment: Ícaro, no momento não consigo te responder, mas já adianto uma pergunta para você: Você já tentou fazer a conversão para byte e novamente para Image sem enviar através da socket? É bem possível que o problema seja na conversão e não na transmissão em si. Aguardo seu retorno e a noite terei o tempo para responder caso ainda não tenha a solução.

Comment: Como você pode ver no primeiro código, eu testo antes da conversão e depois da conversão :/

Comment: Agora eu fiz uma conversão igualzinha à do servidor no final do código que envia do cliente e funcionou, o problema está no servidor, tem alguma coisa que limita a transferência de bytes?

Comment: Resolvi, era o tamanho do buffer de recebimento do cliente, 1024... Tive que colocar em 900000, será que há uma forma de fazer o buffer se extender quando os dados forem maiores que 1024?

Comment: Olá Ícaro. Que bom que resolveu. Mas observe que este site não é um fórum. O ideal é que você mesmo responda à sua pergunta com a solução desse problema, de forma a também ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dificuldade no futuro, e abra uma nova pergunta para a sua nova dúvida. Nesse caso (da nova pergunta) prepare um [mcve], que vai facilitar o entendimento de quem for responder e também facilita você a explicar a dificuldade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido! O buffer do server estava limitado a 1024 bytes, então quando a mensagem era enviada, mal cabia as primeiras linhas de sua matriz dentro de 1024 bytes :)

Comment: Legal que você se preocupou em responder. Mas, eu preciso comentar que a resposta está com baixa qualidade. Basicamente você menciona o que mencionou no comentário. Se você pudesse colocar ao menos algum trecho de código relacionado, com o antes e depois, ficaria mais certo de ajudar também alguém com o mesmo problema no futuro. Caso contrário, a resposta ajuda a sua pergunta a receber voto pra ser fechada como mero "erro de digitação". Entende?